# Rails 3 - Time Comparison?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working to do the following in my Rails App:

if record.updated_at > 15.minutes.ago
  do some stuff
end

Meaning... If the record.updated_at was over 15 minutes ago, do some stuff...

This doesn't seem to be working. Ideas?

Comment: This should actually work just fine I think. You could also try `record.updated_at > (Time.now - 15.minutes)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want:

```
if record.updated_at < 15.minutes.ago
```

That's "less-than" as in "before".

Answer (score 1):

Greater than or less than should work, depending on which you mean. 15.minutes.ago returns a time object that should compare properly with record.updated_at. When you say it "doesn't seem to be working", could you be more specific? Also, if you could show a few more lines of code it may help. For example, if you're doing this all on one line then you're missing some syntax.